# Is there any way to show the special characters when exporting to excel using javascript?

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel

When I used the code below, the special characters do not appear. I used other export methods, but it didn't work as well.  Do you have any suggestions?

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $("#ExcExport").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //getting data from our table
            var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
            var table_div = document.getElementById('List_2');
            var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
            a.download = 'Telefon Listesi' + '.xls';
            a.click();
    
        });
    </script>
```